# Velocity, stringify JSON object in template

Tags: javascript, json, velocity

I have this in my velocity templates:

```
<div>$config.get("locale")</div>
```

I want to have the whole $config object as stringified JSON in a data attribute of a html element so I can access/parse it in my client-side javascript. I thought of something like this:

```
<div data-config="$config.stringify()">...</div>
```

Doesn't seem to work that way - so how can I do that?
Is there something like JSON.stringify in Velocity?

thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a helper function like `stringify()` as part of Velocity, but you can implement one yourself rather easily with something like [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) like this:

```
public String stringify() {
  return (new Gson()).toJson(this);
}
```

Then change your Velocity to look like this:

```
<div data-config="$config.stringify">...</div>
```